# xul : creating a right click context menu item for only hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, xul

I got a question to ask on building firefox plugin, basically my aim is to do following things,

1) In my plugin I want to show right click context menu item for only links[`anchor tags`] and hide the menu item for rest of the page

2) How to add dynamic list to my menu, i.e., adding the number of menu list items dynamically depending upon user's choice.

Can someOne point me to a right direction

Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Bind an event listener for the `contextmenu` event and check whether the clicked element is a link, e.g.:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { 
       var menu = document.getElementById('your-menu-id');
       if(e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
           menu.hidden = false;
       }
       else {
           menu.hidden = true;
       }
   }, false);
   ```

   Read more about [event properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) and the [`menu` element properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menu#Properties).
2. Have a look at the [`menu` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menu)'s [`appendItem` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/appendItem).

Comment: thanks for reply & the links, what are tools required to develop a plugin ? Firefox is making me bit annoying. Every time I made a change in my XUL file, I need to restart my browser. Is there any solution for testing the code w/o restarting the browser  ?

Comment: @rockstarlive: Not so far. Restaring won't be required anymore if you use [JetPack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/). To make restart easy, have a look at [Extension Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434/) and [other development extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_extensions).